# Django - Cannot add middleware

Tags: python, django

I added a middleware `django-user-agents` to my application, used for getting user agent information and now my app won't start up. I followed all steps mentioned on their github page: [django_user_agents](https://github.com/selwin/django-user_agents)
 but cannot get this thing working.

Here's the stacktrace:

```
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.<locals>.wrapper at 0x000000000520B048>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\catch\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python34\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 226, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\catch\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python34\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 142, in inner_run
    handler = self.get_handler(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\catch\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python34\site-packages\django\contrib\staticfiles\management\commands\runserver.py", line 27, in get_handler
    handler = super(Command, self).get_handler(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\catch\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python34\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 64, in get_handler
    return get_internal_wsgi_application()
  File "C:\Users\catch\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python34\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 49, in get_internal_wsgi_application
    return import_string(app_path)
  File "C:\Users\catch\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python34\site-packages\django\utils\module_loading.py", line 20, in import_string
    module = import_module(module_path)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 109, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2254, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2237, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2226, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1200, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1129, in _exec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1471, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 321, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\catch\PycharmProjects\Backend_Noticeboard\noticeboard\noticeboard\wsgi.py", line 16, in <module>
    application = get_wsgi_application()
  File "C:\Users\catch\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python34\site-packages\django\core\wsgi.py", line 14, in get_wsgi_application
    return WSGIHandler()
  File "C:\Users\catch\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python34\site-packages\django\core\handlers\wsgi.py", line 153, in __init__
    self.load_middleware()
  File "C:\Users\catch\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python34\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 82, in load_middleware
    mw_instance = middleware(handler)
TypeError: object() takes no parameters
```

Would be really helpful if someone would figure this out.

Feel free to pop a question in case I missed something/something is not clear.

Thanks in anticipation!! :)

Comment: Which Django version are you using? The setting `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` was deprecated in Django 1.10. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#middleware-classes

Comment: I am using MIDDLEWARE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The middleware you are trying to use seems not to be compatible with Django version >= 1.10. There is already an open issue on GitHub for your exact problem:

https://github.com/selwin/django-user_agents/issues/13

Their workaround right now is to use the old-style `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` setting instead of the `MIDDLEWARE` setting if possible.

Another option from the associated pull request (https://github.com/selwin/django-user_agents/pull/17) is to create your own middleware extending the other middleware:

```
from django.utils.deprecation import MiddlewareMixin
from django_user_agents.middleware import UserAgentMiddleware

class CustomUserAgentMiddleware(MiddlewareMixin, UserAgentMiddleware):
    pass
```

And then in your settings.py:

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    # other middlewares...
    'path.to.your.own.file.CustomUserAgentMiddleware',
]
```

Comment: Thanks. I will try that!

Comment: @DivijSehgal Glad I could help. If this answer helped you please mark it as the answer to your question. This way other people with the same problem know immediately, that this is the solution.